# Compare constant values with actual values using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

TheresholdVal(10) values are more or less 10 `(either +10 or -10)` of actualVal. Beyond of threshold value 10(example) have to show `"Selected value is more thereshold value"`. If it is satified the condition, we have to show `"Successfully matched records"` alerts. I tried below code,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#idMatch").click(function() {
    var theresholdVal = "10";
    var actualVal = "10"; //-examples : 10, -20, 40, 10, 20
    if (
      parseFloat(theresholdVal) <= parseInt(actualVal) &&
      parseFloat(theresholdVal) >= parseFloat(actualVal)
    ) {
      alert("Selected value is more than thereshold value");
    } else {
      alert("Matched successfully");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="idMatch">Match</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you want to do but it seems that you may want to update condition inside `if`. Use `||` instead of `&&` and that should fix your issue.

Comment: Also you should use negative value for `<=` condition. As `parseFloat(theresholdVal) <= -1 * parseInt(actualVal) ||`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check that input value is between +theresholdVal and -theresholdVal then use condition as `Math.abs(parseFloat(theresholdVal)) < Math.abs(parseInt(actualVal))`.

Try it below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#idMatch").click(function() {
    var theresholdVal = "10";
    var actualVal = $("#actualValue").val() || 0; //-examples : 10, -20, 40, 10, 20
    if (Math.abs(parseFloat(theresholdVal)) < Math.abs(parseInt(actualVal))) {
      alert("Selected value is more than thereshold value");
    } else {
      alert("Matched successfully");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="idMatch">Match</button>
<input type="text" id="actualValue" value="10" />
```

Comment: Hi Karan, Thanks for your help. above snippet gives success message for any values.

Comment: Added new input and retrieved actual value from it. Try adding any value that is greater than 10 or less than -10 and you will see alert for `Selected value is more than thereshold value`.